# Application Shortcut created with Advertise='yes' does not show ICON for the shortcut, but shortcut works fine

Tags: wix, wix3

we have WIX installer script that has been working fine for almost few years now. with recent upgrades to the system running **Windows defender, firewall ON, Windows 10, Build: 19044.2673, 21H2** the application shortcuts created by the installer does not show any ICONs.
The shortcut works fine.

we tried following investigations:

1. cleaning ICON cache.
2. clean thumbnails.
3. sfc checks.
4. installer log checks.
5. the system where the issue occurs are under corporate networks with custom policies (I am not able to summarize them though)

None of them show issues/ anything that is suspicious. we want to rule out anything missing from our side.

We installed same Windows 10 build in another clean system which is outside the corporate network and the ICONs work fine.

creating a manual shortcut for the same utility just works fine. WIX Toolset version used: Wix toolset extensions for VS2019. (v3)

Tried all those listed above.

Comment: It probably would be helpful if you provided the actual `Shortcut` and `Icon` related code.

Comment: Hi  Rob
The wix script uses a standard Shortcut tag  to create a shortcut with Advertise = True.
I will try to see if I can post something that I am allowed to do so. but one other finding we have:
we deployed a sandbox VM with the same version of Windows 10 and tried installing the application there. it just works fine.! in the computers that are in a corporate network boundary, seem to be failing to display the icon after installation.